# Quiero sacar más de un grupo de este match del regex

Tags: c#, .net

Mi expresión regular: `([a-z A-Z]+)`

Lo que quiero es sacar varias cadenas de esta cadena, pero solo puedo obtener un grupo y quiero sacar mas de uno.

> C:\AddonMigracion\SQL\1[14]Busquedas[237]Autorizacion en OC.txt

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aclara sobre que cadenas lograste los match y cuales fallan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa el método [Regex.Matches](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.7.2), este devuelve todas las coincidencias

```
var input = @"C:\AddonMigracion\SQL\1[14]Busquedas[237]Autorizacion en OC.txt";
var regex = new Regex("([a-z A-Z]+)");

var result = regex.Matches(input);
//  { [C], [AddonMigracion], [SQL], [Busquedas], [Autorizacion en OC], [txt] }
```